# getting a dojo node when I have the store item id

Tags: dojo

I have a `dijit.Tree` that's populated by a `ItemFileReadStore` using JSON. Because of our setup, I need to do a new request each time a tree node is clicked. The tree is using cookies to remember which folders were expanded and not, so that's not a problem. But I'm trying to set focus to the node that was clicked.

I've managed to get the item from the store model by setting its id as a parameter in the url:

```
store.fetchItemByIdentity({identity:openNode, onItem:focusOpenNode(item)});
function focusOpenNode(item) {
    //I've got the item, now how do I get the node so I can do:
    var node = getNodeFromItem(item); //not a real method...
    treeControl.focusNode(node);
}
```

but I can't seem to find a way to get the matching node from the item id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the treeControl, pass in as one of the params in the constructor params or use dojo.mixin to add to the tree widget:

```
/*tree helper function to get the tree node for a store item*/
getNodeFromItem: function (item) {  
    return this._itemNodesMap[item.name[0]];
}
```

(It would be neater to use the tree's store getAttribute to get the name of the item - but this example is not polished.)

Then you could do:

```
function focusOpenNode(item) {
    //I've got the item, now how do I get the node so I can do:

    var node = treeControl.getNodeFromItem(item); //now a real method...
    treeControl.focusNode(node);
}
```

Comment: Sweeet! I wish I could give you multiple upvotes for that one. Works like a charm. And good idea to put custom functions on the treeControl, helps clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, I've seen this done in a variety of ways, but this is the simplest (and best).

I had to modify it a bit because of how I'm using the control.

Instead of `this._itemNodesMap[item.name[0]]`, I use `this._itemNodesMap[item.id]`